# How to trigger and move to next stage in pipeline using Jenkins CLI?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have three stages in my pipeline.

1. Build
2. Deploy
3. Test

And i am going to trigger this pipeline remotely using jenkins CLI and then promote it to next stages based on need. Is there any CLI commands to trigger a pipeline to move to next stage?

Comment: Just add an input to the end of each stage and you will be able to trigger that. Otherwise there's no promoting to next stage this happens automatically.

Comment: Thanks Hakamairi. What kind of input you mean here, can you please elaborate?
I already have choice parameter input with Yes or No option after each stage. Is it enough to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have only initiated build using jenkins-cli.jar with authenticated tokens in CLI. Rest i don't know how to proceed. I couldn't find any cli command to trigger to next stage.

Comment: Why would the stages be blocked? Normally they aren't, I'm so confused with your question ;)

Comment: I need some manual intervention before promoting to next stage. So, i have added approval process as a input in between each stage.

Comment: Sure @Karthick, I've posted an example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input as the blocking part, like

```
stage {
    steps {
        //other steps, and finally the input
        input id: 'Input1', message: 'Deploy to Production?'
    }
}
```

For remotely triggering just do

```
https://[jenkins_base_URL]/job/[job_name]/[build_id]/input/Input1/proceedEmpty
```

If it would complain about crumb

```
https://MY_JENKINS_RUL/crumbIssuer/api/json
```